# API - List all addresses in given zip code

Tags: gis, street-address

Does anyone know of an API out there that will return all addresses for a given zip code?  I'm aware of zipinfo's product, but that's a physical list that would exist on my server and I was hoping for an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://w10.melissadata.com/lookups/index.htm or google mailing lists.